getting INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE error on field update with API call
I'm getting the INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE error when trying to update the field of master-detail relation.

Can you change the field manually within the record page?

We can't read your mind, see your screen, or log into your org. The more information you can provide, the better. You should [edit] your question to include more information.

@Raghu do you mind providing a bit more context?
This error typically occurs when you try to insert or update a field that is not writable. This can happen in several scenarios, including:
Read-Only fields, protected fields, Field-Level security, fields inaccessible via API, validation rules, etc.
You might want to identify the field, the process trying to perform the update, and check your permissions.

Most standard Master-Detail relationships, such as OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId, can't be updated. Custom Master-Detail relationships can be configured to allow reparenting or not. If you're using a standard field, this error likely indicates it is a relationship that cannot be reparented. If this is a custom relationship, this indicates that reparenting is disabled.
